Voluntary sign up to digest email from QSE
In another post here (Anything we can do to bring dormant high-rep users back?), we discussed how to bring inactive users back to participating at QSE. Having been less active recently myself, I realized how much I'd appreciate once-a-quarter email with:

3 best rated questions

3 best rated answers

3 unanswered questions in my highest-rated tags (i.e. if there are 3 unanswered in my highest-rated tag, then I'd want those three, otherwise then move gradually down via my highest-rated tags).


It would be great if the user could opt in for such digest-email via their profile settings.
What does the community think about such proposal? If this gets enough upvotes, could we then try to have that implemented?

I don't think this will be done by StackExchange themselves as a weekly digest (search for quant) already exists. Could you list more advantages or your proposal? Or would you want a quarterly digest instead of a weekly digest?

I don't know the legality of this. Do users have to explicitly sign up to this? or would it mean amended TaCs for users. Not sure of the impact of GDPR for European users.

@Attack68 It would have to be "opt-in" (so users have to voluntarily sign up to this new feature), rather than "opt-out" (i.e. everyone being signed up automatically and then having to unsubscribe). You are correct that GDPR would certainly be an issue if signing up was automatic.

@BobJansen: main advantage is that less active users probably don't want to be "bombarded" by weekly emails. But once-a-quarter digest with only 3 top-rated questions, 3 top-rated answers and 3 unanswered questions in a top-tag would be a welcome "reminder" of QSE and could well stimulate users to visit the site again or even engage in some Q&A.

Good to clear that up, I'm not sure this will be implemented but I can see the benefit so I tagged the question accordingly.

Thank you @BobJansen, really appreciate this, very helpful and cooperative as always :). Let's give it our best shot and see :)

I certainly like the idea. Similar information seems to be available anyway (at least for users with $\geq$2,000 rep). Thus, it shouldn't be too difficult to display that information more prominently/send it out to interested users?


I marked this as status decline because as Bob Jansen mentioned digests for sites already exist.
Also in my experience as a community manager digests and emails aren't often an effective way to bring people back to participating.
What I am curious about though is hearing some of your ideas around community engagement and retention.
Why do you think people drop off from participating?
Are there tools or support you could receive from Community Managers that you feel would help with keeping members of Quantitative Finance engaged?
I'd love to hear your thoughts and ideas. Please leave them in the comments.

My genuine suggestion to increase participation was the quarterly digest email :) I came up with the idea after being inactive for a while myself, after which I asked myself the question what would bring me back to QSE: the answer I gave myself was that I'd want to see the three highest-rated questions and answers (rather than having to search for them) and also highest-rated unanswered questions in my tags. But not too frequently, only 4 times per year, i.e. once per quarter: is such a feauture availble now?
